# Divide textcontent from DB in paragraphs

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a pice of text stored i my db :

```
model.Description : "Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet fatback pork belly swine cow drumstick jowl"
```

In my view, i would like to divide the text like this:

```
<p>
     Bacon ipsum dolor
</p>
<p>
     sit amet fatback por
</p>
<p>
     belly swine cow drumstick
</p>
```

I want the text to be divided with linebreaks..Is there a way to accomplish this?
Its the linebreaks im after, in any possible way..

EDIT:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Products)
{
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h4>@item.animage</h4>
            <h5>- @item.anotherimage -</h5>
            <br>

            <p>
                @item.Description    <---This is the one to divide!
            </p>           
        </div>
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't explain what algorithm of division you want to use.
This code will divide all your words into paragraphs.

```
string[] words = Text.Split(' ');
@foreach( string word in words )
    <p> @word </p>
```

Use your model.Description instead of Text string

EDIT :
Use this code in respective place

```
@{
    string[] words = item.Descritpion.Split(' ');
    int wordsPerLine = 25;
    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; )
    {
        <p>
            @for (int j = 0; j < wordsPerLine && i < words.Length; i++, j++)
            {
                @words[i]
            }
        </p>
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm..I get an error trying to use your code..Maybe its because im already in a foreach? Please see  my edit!

Comment: you want to divide Description for each item or what you want to do ?

Comment: Lets say that @item.Description contains a string with 100 words. I would like to split each 25 words to a new paragraph.

Comment: and you want to do that for each item as i understood from code above ?

Comment: Well no...only for the @item.Description...The other two items are images...So i guess i should ues another foreach in the first one somehow?